# can not run Qi4j two minutes tutorial

Tags: apache-zest

I am trying to run the project in 'Qi4j in 2 minutes' tutorial

while I can`t find the Qi4j lib files in the maven repository.

Can anyone tell me how to import the Qi4j lib files with maven?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qi4j SDK 2.0 is under development. If you want to use 2.0 you can download builds from Qi4j continuous integration or build the Qi4j SDK from source.

Weekly SNAPSHOTs are uploaded to https://repository-qi4j.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/ so you need to add this url as a maven repository :

```
<repositories>
    [...]
    <repository>
        <id>qi4j-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://repository-qi4j.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    [...]
</repositories>
```

And then you can add dependencies to Qi4j:

```
<dependencies>
    [...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.qi4j.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.qi4j.core.bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.qi4j.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.qi4j.core.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    [...]
</dependencies>
```

All this information can now be found on the Qi4j website, see http://qi4j.org/howto-depend-on-qi4j.html

Comment: Glad to help. If you have any other question, don't hesitate to post them here on SO.